# INSERT OVERWRITE not deleting items, not working

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-dynamodb, hiveql

I have an external table in Hive called "ddb_betaaccounthistory" that links to a DynamoDB table.

Schema is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ddb_betaaccounthistory (
customer_id STRING,
date_action_id STRING,
`date` BIGINT,
action STRING,
client STRING,
ddbkmsig BINARY,
action_description BINARY,
reason STRING
time_to_live BIGINT)
STORED BY ...
```

time_to_live has some NULL fields in some rows because it isn't fully filled in.

I am trying to DELETE all items with a "date" attribute older than this timestamp: 1586551523, which is 18 months in the past, April 10, 2020, and keep all items after this date.

I have tried this query. From my understanding, this hive query should KEEP the items that were created after this unix timestamp  1586551523 and delete everything else:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ddb_betaaccounthistory
SELECT * FROM ddb_betaaccounthistory
WHERE `date` > 1586551523;
```

I have also tried this and it still doesn't delete anything from the table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ddb_betaaccounthistory
SELECT * FROM ddb_betaaccounthistory
WHERE `date` > unix_timestamp() - 47340000;
```

`Date` formatted as a unix timestamp.

The number of items in the external table ddb_betaaccounthistory remains the same after running the INSERT OVERWRITE statements. And my DynamoDB table has no items deleted after the query.

I have checked that there are indeed Writes being consumed on my Dynamo table when I run the hive query, so I know it's being linked properly to Dynamo table.

Is there something wrong with my hive query? I have no idea why the INSERT OVERWRITE isn't deleting items from my table.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls try

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ddb_betaaccounthistory
SELECT * FROM ddb_betaaccounthistory
WHERE  unix_timestamp(`date`)> 1586551523
```

I think the column date is a timestamp datatype and you need to convert to unix time to compare.

Comment: I got the following error when I ran this. `Date` is a LONG datatype, so it gave me

```Wrong arguments `date`. The function UNIX_TIMESTAMP takes only string/timestamp/timestampwltz types```

Comment: Hive doesnt have a long datatype. Is `date` a bigint? Then your query should be fine. But since its not working, can you convert it to datetime and check using from_unixtime(`date`) > some_date. Its possible this field is null in database.

Comment: Yes `date` is mapped to a BIGINT in HIve. But for some reason my query is still not deleting any rows. One of the attributes that is named `time_to_live` in ddb_betaaccounthistory is NULL in some rows. Not every row has a `time_to_live` attribute. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yep,null can be q problem.in hive null compared to anything will result as false.